# Astropy Table with source positions save in CASA Region Format

Tags: python, astropy

I have an Astropy Table instance of the CORNISH highly reliable detections (ie. http://cornish.leeds.ac.uk/public/catalogue.php first entry). I want to save it into a CASA region file so I can load it in CASA viewer to see the position of the detected sources.

Is there a python module that can help out with this? Perhaps someone has a script lying around? pyRegion only creates DS9 region files. Worst case  I will just have to write my own script to do it (as per https://casaguides.nrao.edu/index.php?title=CASA_Region_Format), but I wanted to check if someone had solved this issue before.

For completeness here is a small snippet showing the data in question (I filter out a certain region of the survey to make the table smaller):

```
data = ascii.read('http://cornish.leeds.ac.uk/cgibin/public/catalogue_query.py?title=sigma7&type=CSV&artifacts=0')
data_selection = data[(data['l_deg']<47.5) * (data['l_deg']>40)]
data_selection[:5]
```

[image]

As you can see the image is from Jupyter notebook and it cannot fit the whole width of the table conveniently, but the important coordinate fields are there.

Comment: CASA region reading/writing does not yet exist as part of the astropy-regions (https://github.com/astropy/regions) project, but it is something we really want.  https://github.com/astropy/regions/issues/119